# How to have the project launched in CTRL+F5

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to know in which file the project that starts when we do CTRL+F5 or F5 on VS is written.

I've already looked in the .sln file but I didn't find anything.

I don't want to do it directly from VS but from the solution files

Comment: yes sorry i edit my message

Comment: @UsamaAziz OP is asking which _project_ will be started.

Comment: Hi again, hm, I have the .suo file but i can't find were it say wich project is the start one